# Draw opaque lines onto translucent TBitmap

Tags: delphi, bitmap, drawing, alpha-transparency, translucency

I’ve got an empty bitmap, and I’ve got a drawing routine that receives a TCanvas.  The drawing routine is part of a larger library, and so effectively out of my control.

Simply put: I want the pixels to be opaque if the drawing routines affect them; each pixel that isn’t touched should be left transparent.  Since I have no control over the colours that will be used by the drawing routines, I would prefer not having to use the `TransparentColor` property.

Is there a way of achieving this?  Some kind of setting I can use to specify that the canvas should affect the alpha layer of the pixels it’s drawing onto?

---

**Update**: I’m using Delphi 2010, and here follows the code I’ve tried:

```
Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
try
  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Bmp.Transparent := False;
  Bmp.SetSize(Width, Height);

  // Ensure all pixels are black with opacity 0 (= fully transparent)
  ScanlineWidth := Width * SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
  for y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do begin
    ZeroMemory(Bmp.ScanLine[y], ScanlineWidth);
  end;

  // call drawing routines here
  DrawContours(Bmp.Canvas, Width, Height);

  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  Bmp.SaveToFile(OwnPath + 'Contours-' + IntToStr(GetTickCount) + '.bmp');
  {$ENDIF}

  Result := Bmp.ReleaseHandle;
finally
  Bmp.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Set the bitmap to be 32bpp and just draw to it. You might have to initialise all the pixels to be transparent first - set the alpha values to 0.  In my experience you'll get better results more easily with something like graphics32.  Then you can even use anti-aliasing to make your lines look better.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Tried that: I set the bitmap to 32bpp and set the alpha values to 0; but after drawing everything, the resulting bitmap still had alpha values of 0 for all pixels...

Comment: What version of Delphi? Modern ones are better at alpha. Also, if you could give us a code sample that showed what you have tried that might help.

Comment: I wonder if your problem is that you are saving to a .bmp file. I know of no image editor that can handle 32bpp .bmp files even though HBITMAPs with 32bpp are fine internally. Could you perhaps try assigning to a TPNGImage and saving that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: also tried that; alas, no joy.  BTW, both [the GIMP](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable) and [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) can read and write 32-bit BMP files with alpha transparency.

Comment: @Martijn: Correcting myself: Paint.Net can read 32-bit BMP files with alpha transparency (as saved by the GIMP), but it seems to want to write 24-bits BMP files only.  The GIMP handles it all without a hitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach could be an option if drawing is not expensive. Draw three times, once onto your transparent bitmap, once to a 1-bit bitmap with white background and once to a 1-bit bitmap with black background to obtain the changes you need to make to the alpha channel (because Tim is right - the bitmap initially is completely transparent; we need to find the pixels to make opaque).

**Edit:** The first version used only one 1-bit bitmap which had a white background. This unfortunately didn't detect lighter paintings. So lets go one step further and make it two 1-bit bitmaps. Although with more and more bitmaps it is getting equally less elegant.

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  ScanlineWidth: Integer;
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
  // this one will track dark paintings
  BmpBitMaskWhite:TBitmap;
  // this one will track light paintings
  BmpBitMaskBlack:TBitmap;
  Row32bit, Row1bitWhite, Row1bitBlack:PByteArray;
  ByteAccess:Byte;

  // Init bitmaps needed for tracking pixels we need to change the alpha channel for
  procedure InitAlphaMaskBitmaps;
  begin
    BmpBitMaskWhite.PixelFormat:=pf1bit;          // <= one bit is enough
    BmpBitMaskWhite.Transparent:=False;
    BmpBitMaskWhite.SetSize(Width, Height);
    BmpBitMaskWhite.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;  // <= fill white; changes can then be seen as black pixels
    BmpBitMaskWhite.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Width, Height));

    BmpBitMaskBlack.PixelFormat:=pf1bit;          // <= one bit is enough
    BmpBitMaskBlack.Transparent:=False;
    BmpBitMaskBlack.SetSize(Width, Height);
    BmpBitMaskBlack.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clBlack;  // <= fill black; changes can then be seen as white pixels
    BmpBitMaskBlack.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Width, Height));
  end;

begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  BmpBitMaskWhite:=TBitmap.Create;
  BmpBitMaskBlack:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bmp.Transparent := False;
    Bmp.SetSize(Width, Height);

    InitAlphaMaskBitmaps;

    // ensure all pixels are black with opacity 0 (= fully transparent)
    ScanlineWidth := Width * SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
    for y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do
    begin
      ZeroMemory(Bmp.ScanLine[y], ScanlineWidth);
    end;

    // call drawing routines here
    DrawContours(Bmp.Canvas, Width, Height);
    // call again to get areas where we need to un-transparent the Bmp (this is for dark paintings)
    DrawContours(BmpBitMaskWhite.Canvas, Width, Height);
    // call again to get areas where we need to un-transparent the Bmp  (this is for light paintings)
    DrawContours(BmpBitMaskBlack.Canvas, Width, Height);

    // modify alpha channel of Bmp by checking changed pixels of BmpBitMaskWhite and BmpBitMaskBlack
    // iterate all lines
    for y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do
    begin
      // iterate all pixels
      for x := 0 to Bmp.Width - 1 do
      begin
        Row32bit:=PByteArray(Bmp.ScanLine[y]);
        Row1bitWhite:=PByteArray(BmpBitMaskWhite.ScanLine[y]);
        Row1bitBlack:=PByteArray(BmpBitMaskBlack.ScanLine[y]);

        // Now we need to find the changed bits in BmpBitMaskWhite and BmpBitMaskBlack to modify the corresponding
        // alpha-byte in Bmp. Black areas (Bit=0) in BmpBitMaskWhite are the ones that
        // have been drawn to, as well as white areas (Bit=1) in BmpBitMaskBlack.
        // Not pretty, but works.
        ByteAccess:=1 shl (7-x mod 8);
        if ((Row1bitWhite[x div 8] and ByteAccess)=0) or
           ((Row1bitBlack[x div 8] and ByteAccess)<>0) then
        begin
          Row32bit[x*4+3]:=255;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    {$IFDEF DEBUG}
    Bmp.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\Contours-' + IntToStr(GetTickCount) + '.bmp');
    BmpBitMaskWhite.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\Contours-' + IntToStr(GetTickCount) + '_BitMaskWhite.bmp');
    BmpBitMaskBlack.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\Contours-' + IntToStr(GetTickCount) + '_BitMaskBlack.bmp');
    {$ENDIF}

//    Result := Bmp.ReleaseHandle;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
    BmpBitMaskWhite.Free;
    BmpBitMaskBlack.Free;
  end;
```

By the way: the only program which showed me the transparency in these bitmaps properly was [PixelFormer](http://www.qualibyte.com/pixelformer/). The others (Gimp, IrfanView, Windows Fax thingy, FastStone Image Viewer, MS Paint) all colored the transparent area black.

Comment: But if the drawing function draws something in black, it won’t show up on the mask either, or will it?

Comment: You are right, although the problem is the other way round. My version did not detect changes made in lighter colors. Please see my revised version. I am not really happy with this but it seems to work. Maybe the general idea could be implemented in a similar and more elegant way. But I don't know right now if there are mechanisms to track changes made to a TCanvas or HDC.

Comment: Whoa, that means drawing thrice.  I’m afraid this is going to be a bit of a performance penalty.

Comment: Yep. Maybe something similar could be achieved by calculating a difference image before and after drawing. This would give you the changed pixels as well and the general logic of the code above could be applied while only having to paint once. (BitBlt with SRCINVERT operation could be a good candidate)

Comment: You could at least go down to two paints by doing one BitBlt with SRCINVERT (which detect changes not made in the background color of the image) and one additional paint to a monochrome bitmap which covers paintings in background color.

Comment: This is the more surefire way I’ve found so far.  Draw once with TransparentColor set to black, and use that to extract a mask bitmap; draw a second time onto a pf1bit white bitmap to figure out what really is black; subtract that second mask from the first mask, and you’ve got the actual mask to be applied to the first (coloured) bitmap.  Thanks a lot, Heinrich!

Answer (score 1):

**If I understand correctly**:
You are getting a completely transparent bitmap every time.

**Suggestions**
You could rewrite the `DrawContours` function to set an alpha value to each area of the canvas it draws on. I would suggest this route but I think you mentioned somewhere that you didn't want to rewrite these functions.

The only other options I can think of is to (since your beginning bmp is all black and all transparent) after you pass it to the `DrawContrours` function inspect each pixel and if it is no longer black then change the alpha to 255. But this has the same result as simply using the transparent color and property which you have already said you did not want to use.

**Thoughts**:
I do not know of a way (and am skeptical that there even is one) to change the bitmap such that whatever drawing routine you pass it to would treat it differently than the routine was designed.

**Final Answer**:
Rewrite the drawing routine `DrawContrours` or use `Transparent color`

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question: DrawContours is actually a function in a library — I can’t change it.  And I’d rather not use `TransparentColor`...  So far, depending on several settings, either I get a completely transparent bitmap, or a completely opaque one.  Anyway, thanks for answering!

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark and I have not thought through it completely but what if you were to create a class that inherited the bitmap you were sending through to the function. Then in this new class you could override all of the drawing methods that affect the canvas and before you perform the drawing in each and every method set the pen and brush to be opaque, draw as intended (calling the parent class function), then set the pen and brush back. This needs more work to even be a plausible idea but its an idea.

Comment: That sounds like a _lot_ of work... :-)  But I think this could be done using the [Graphics32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphics32/) which provides a TCanvas.  Great idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with several options, I got the following to work:

- Set the pixel format to 32-bits;
- Set the `AlphaFormat` to `afIgnored`;
- Set `Transparent` to True; (this one is important)
- Clear the alpha values;
- Call the drawing routine;
- Then assign the bitmap to PNG, and save that.

In code:

```
Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
try
  Bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  Bmp.AlphaFormat := afIgnored;
  Bmp.Transparent := True;

  Bmp.SetSize(Width, Height);

  // Make bitmap fully transparent
  ScanlineWidth := Width * SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
  for y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do begin
    ZeroMemory(Bmp.ScanLine[y], ScanlineWidth);
  end;

  DrawContours(Bmp.Canvas);

  PNG := TPNGImage.Create;
  try
    PNG.Assign(Bmp);
    PNG.SaveToFile('contours.png'); // => this one has the wanted transparency!
  finally
    PNG.Free;
  end;
finally
  Bmp.Free;
end;
```

Comment: To satisfy my curiosity could you try setting the BMP.Transparent color to something other than black (if it defaults to black), perhaps clBlue. and see what happens? I have a suspicion that this is using the transparent color property set to black and thus giving you the desired results. And if this is the case then if any black is drawn by the function you are passing into then it will be transparent.

Comment: @Tim: Drat, you’re right.  It’s actually making everything black into transparent.